# Fetching JSON result

Tags: javascript, php, json

What I need to do here is to fetch the result that I get from `info.php` file.

This is info.php:

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=csgo', 'root', '');

$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users");

$row = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($row as $r){
    $steamids = $r['steam_id'];

    $APIKEY = '********';
    $steamAPI = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?steamids=$steamids&key=$APIKEY&format=json";
    $json_object= file_get_contents($steamAPI);
    echo $json_object;
}
```

This is app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("/info.php", function(json){
       $("#userinfo").html('<img style="width: 100px; height: 100px" style="width: 100px; height: 100px" src="'+json.response.players[0].avatarfull+'">');
       $("#steamProfile").html('<a href="'+json.response.players[0].profileurl+'">STEAM nuoroda</a>');
       $("#personaname").html(json.response.players[0].personaname);
    });
});
```

How should I correctly fetch in my app.js ?

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("/info.php", function(json){
        $.each(json.response, function(i, player){
       $("#userinfo").html('<img style="width: 100px; height: 100px" style="width: 100px; height: 100px" src="'+player.players.avatarfull+'">');
       /*$("#steamProfile").html('<a href="'+json.response.players[0].profileurl+'">STEAM nuoroda</a>');
       $("#personaname").html(json.response.players[0].personaname);*/
       });
    });
});
```

Now I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP file will output several unrelated JSON blobs one after the other, e.g.:

```
{..}{..}{..}
```

That makes it unparsable to a JSON parser. You'll have to decode the data and construct a new valid JSON structure:

```
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$data = [];

foreach ($sth as $r) { // no need to `fetchAll`
    ...
    $json = file_get_contents($steamAPI);
    $data[] = json_decode($json);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Now I should use $.each in my js file ?

Comment: Does `json.response` exist...? Probably you just want to iterate over `json` itself?! Inspect what you're working with using `console.log(json)`.

Comment: Okay if I iterate over `json` I get this `[Object Object]` if I iterate over `json.response` I get nothing.

Comment: Okay if I do like this: `player.response.players[0].avatarfull` I get only one player, but I have two rows the same. But I only get info for the first one and not the second one. They're both in `info.php`

Comment: I have done it! I needed to use `class` on div instead of `id`